# Howto implement a OData service for a file system

Tags: .net, web-services, odata

If I want to create an OData service that represents my filesystem, how would I go about that ?

The easy way would be to take a copy of the filesystem and save in a database, and then create the odata service on top of that. But it would be much slicker if there was a way of creating a context based on the actual filesystem.

Huh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a custom provider which can then do whatever you need in regard of getting the data from somewhere. Take a look at this series of how to implement a custom provider: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx
There are also samples available at http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk (OData Provider Toolkit).
The tricky part of exposing file system is to define the data model. For example, what would be your primary key for a file (note that it has to be unique for the entire service). It is definitely doable though.

Answer (score 3):

This is something i found out recently. There is a tool kit available from @lostintangent on Codeplex known as WCF Data Services Toolkit. This will allow you to expose data from any data source as an OData feed but with minimalistic approach.

See if that can help you in any way. The examples shown is of a OData service which actually talks to instagram API and provides the data.

Here are the links:

http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/

One of my friend has a complete walkthro on using this toolkit:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2011/05/23/wcf-data-services-toolkit-to-talk-to-any-database-using-getall-getone-save-remove-methods.aspx

hope it helps you.